# How to Make a form not open a new window when it submits a url action?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have a form that submits a url action. However I don't want it to open up a new window with the url when it is submitted. How should I avoid this?

```
<form name="leds" id="ledSend" method="get" target="_blank" action="https://agent.electricimp.com/Fk43xPMkSrWF">
Lamp Control: <input type="radio" name="led" value="0" checked>Off
            <input type="radio" name="led" value="1">On<br>
How long should the Lights stay on? <input type="text" name="timer" value="10">seconds<br>
Your name? For Our Records <input id="name" type="text" name="user" placeholder="Your name here">       <br>
<input type="submit" value="Update!" onclick="alert(theInput.value)"/>
<script>
```

var theInput = document.getElementById("name");

I don't want this form to change windows to

```
https://agent.electricinp.com
```

When it is submitted. How would I avoid this so that the user stays on the original page where they submit the form form.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of `target="_blank"`

```
<form name="leds" id="ledSend" method="get" action="">
```

Comment: This still leaves the original page and goes to https://agent.electricimp.com/Fk43xPMkSrWF

Comment: That's where you send them. What did you expect to happen?

Comment: Is there a way to stay on the original page but still make the http request to the site?

Comment: Yes, change the form action to the URL you want it to go to

Comment: I think OP is looking for AJAX submit

Comment: im think he needs to curl to submit form to *remote* site

Comment: If you don't want the page to refresh you need to use Ajax

Comment: I want to be able to submit the form and have it go to the site in the url. But I want to stay on the original url where the form was submitted from. I will look into curl to submit forms.

Comment: That's waaaayyyyy too broad for this website

Answer (score 0):

Recently I got this scenario and researched a lot to find the hack/solution.

**Solution** - If you can put a window names and refer same every time, then browser will make sure to open new tab if not opened already, otherwise it will just refresh the window.

Example snippet: [Demo JSfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/5cbx3yj9/)

```
<form id="myForm" action="<URL>" method="POST" target="_blank" onsubmit="target_popup(this)">
    First name: <input type="text" name="fname"/><br/>
    Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"/><br/>
    <button type="submit" id="btnTest"> Submit</button>
</form>


<script>
var target_popup = function(form) {
    window.open('',//URL should be blank so that it will take form attributes.
                'UniqueWindowName', //window name
                'width=400,height=400,resizeable,scrollbars');
    form.target = 'UniqueWindowName';
}
</script>
```

Please refer my [blog](https://pradeep-dani.blogspot.com/2018/11/make-html-form-to-not-open-new-window.html) for more details